# jenkins 1.5.20 master goes offline with too low temp space

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins 1.520, i have 500mb in /tmp on linux (RHEL6 host), 500mb is plenty of space for our current build size and number of projects, how can i make this message go away and have my master node be online?

I looked around for bugs that apply to this version, did not find any. I tried previous suggestions found in stackoverflow, do not seem to work or simply do not apply.

```
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/
/dev/mapper/vg00-tmp  504M   23M  456M   5% /tmp
```

..thanks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure the Free Disk Space and Free Temp Space thresholds in the Node configuration, `http://jenkins:8080/computer/configure` (or from the Jenkins main page -> *Build Executor Status* -> *Configure*).